# Show that the Hessian matrix of f at the origin is not symmetric.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let$f:R^2 \rightarrow R$ be defined by

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$
and $f(x,y)=0$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$

I was asked to show that the Hessian matrix of f at the origin is not symmetric, but I don't know where to begin from.

I also don't know how to find the Jacobian matrix of these kind of functions.

Edit: I forgot to add “at the origin” in the problem.

Comment: Do you have a typo? $y^2$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this statement holds correctly. This is because we have most often the following property:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}
=
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x},
$$
as holds here, implying that the Hessian matrix is symmetric.

Comment: I forgot to type “at the origin”. Is that still the same?